# HTML/Javascript Double-Dropdown not Working

Tags: javascript, html

I setup a double drop down following this guide: http://coursesweb.net/javascript/multiple-select-dropdown-list-javascript_t#doublesl

I added my own options and it seems as if the 2nd drop-down does not display anymore. 
Why could this be?

```
    <!-- The first select list -->
Select WebSite: <select name="slist1" onchange="SList.getSelect('slist2', this.value);">
 <option>- - -</option>
 <option value="amazon">Amazon</option>
 <option value="apple">Apple</option>
 <option value="keurig">Keurig</option>
 <option value="nike">Nike</option>
</select>
<!-- Tags for the seccond dropdown list, and for text-content -->
<span id="slist2"></span> <div id="scontent"></div>

<script><!--
/* Script Double Select Dropdown List, from: coursesweb.net/javascript/ */
var SList = new Object();             // JS object that stores data for options

// HERE replace the value with the text you want to be displayed near Select
var txtsl2 = 'Select Category:';

/*
 Property with options for the Seccond select list
 The key in this object must be the same with the values of the options added in the first select
 The values in the array associated to each key represent options of the seccond select
*/
SList.slist2 = {
 "amazon": ['kindle fire hd', 'kindle charger', 'kindle fire hd'],
 "apple": ['macbook', 'imac', 'iphone', 'ipad']
 "keurig": ['platinum', 'vue']
 "nike": ['fuel band']
};


/*
 Property with text-content associated with the options of the 2nd select list
 The key in this object must be the same with the values (options) added in each Array in "slist2" above
 The values of each key represent the content displayed after the user selects an option in 2nd dropdown list
*/
SList.scontent = {
 "kindle fire hd": 'www.marplo.net/ajax/',
 "kindle charger": 'www.marplo.net/jocuri/',
 "kindle fire hd": 'www.marplo.net/anime/',
 "macbook": 'coursesweb.net/php-mysql/',
 "imac": 'coursesweb.net/javascript/',
 "iphone": 'coursesweb.net/flash/',
 "ipad": 'www.marplo.net/ajax/',
 "platinum": 'www.marplo.net/jocuri/',
 "vue": 'www.marplo.net/anime/',
 "fuelband": 'coursesweb.net/php-mysql/'
};

    /* From here no need to modify */

// function to get the dropdown list, or content
SList.getSelect = function(slist, option) {
  document.getElementById('scontent').innerHTML = '';           // empty option-content

  if(SList[slist][option]) {
    // if option from the last Select, add text-content, else, set dropdown list
    if(slist == 'scontent') document.getElementById('scontent').innerHTML = SList[slist][option];
    else if(slist == 'slist2') {
      var addata = '<option>- - -</option>';
      for(var i=0; i<SList[slist][option].length; i++) {
        addata += '<option value="'+SList[slist][option][i]+'">'+SList[slist][option][i]+'</option>';
      }

      document.getElementById('slist2').innerHTML = txtsl2+' <select name="slist2" onchange="SList.getSelect(\'scontent\', this.value);">'+addata+'</select>';
    }
  }
  else if(slist == 'slist2') {
    // empty the tag for 2nd select list
    document.getElementById('slist2').innerHTML = '';
  }
}
--></script>
```

Comment: Have you checked for syntax or other errors?

Comment: I ran it through JSLint and nothing seems to be a red flag...

Comment: Tools like JSLint & JSHint are useful, but noting beats the browser for telling you what is wrong when code doesn't work in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple check of a console would show that you have a sytax error. Step one when something is not working is check for javascript errors!

You are missing commas in the `SList.slist2` object, which seperates the objects in the array (or hash table if you prefer)

You want:

```
SList.slist2 = {
 "amazon": ['kindle fire hd', 'kindle charger', 'kindle fire hd'],
 "apple": ['macbook', 'imac', 'iphone', 'ipad'],
 "keurig": ['platinum', 'vue'],
 "nike": ['fuel band']
};
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/A32k5/1/

Comment: This always happens to me! Oh well. :)

Answer (score 1):

Find

```
SList.slist2 = {
 "amazon": ['kindle fire hd', 'kindle charger', 'kindle fire hd'],
 "apple": ['macbook', 'imac', 'iphone', 'ipad']
 "keurig": ['platinum', 'vue']
 "nike": ['fuel band']
};
```

You are missing your commas. Should be:

```
SList.slist2 = {
 "amazon": ['kindle fire hd', 'kindle charger', 'kindle fire hd'],
 "apple": ['macbook', 'imac', 'iphone', 'ipad'],
 "keurig": ['platinum', 'vue'],
 "nike": ['fuel band']
};
```

**IMPORTANT:** In The future, please provide some extra details on your question. Run it through JSHint, and perhaps provide a fiddle.

Hope this helps!